# Angular and RxJs - why the entire RxJs lib is brought into the bundle by webpack/CLI

Tags: angular, webpack, rxjs, angular-cli

I am developing a Angular app using RxJs.

I have been careful avoid using

```
import 'rxjs'
```

I just do imports such as

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Unfortunately though, when I create the distribution package via

```
ng build --prod
```

I see via **webpack-bundle-analyzer** that the entire **RxJs** library has been imported in  the final bundle.
Is there any abvious reason for this?
In general, is it possible to understand which is the module responsible for importing another module by looking at the **stats.json**?

Here is my package.json if it can help

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're sure that your code doesn't import it all, you probably have a third part library importing for you... But honestly this is weird, especially according to your `package.json` which doesn't have much.

Comment: I am searching in my code base for `import 'rxjs'` and I do not find any place where I am using it. Is there any other thing I should avoid doing?

Comment: Is the project open source? Can you share a link to it? Hard to say just like that.

Comment: Check also for `import 'rxjs/Rx'`

Comment: I do have few things like `import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Rx';` Can these be the culprits?

Comment: Maybe `import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription'` is better? ("rxjs": "^5.1.0")

Comment: I just saw your question and run webpack analyzer on our project as well. What is the size of your rxjs bundle?

Comment: stat size 686.9 KB, parsed size 198.15 KB, gzipped size 34.01 KB

Comment: @Picci You should never import from neither `rxjs` nor `rxjs/Rx`. For more details see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7591

Comment: Thanks to your comments I was able to solve the problem. The likes of 'import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Rx';' where the culprits.